# Getting .netcoreapp3.0 runtimes when targeting .net6

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-6.0

\bin\Release\net6.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netcoreapp3.0\System.Drawing.Common.dll
\bin\Release\net6.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netcoreapp3.0\System.Drawing.Common.dll

When running "mend" scans in my project, it identified a vulnerability with the above dll. However, my target is only .net6 which should bring the no-vulnerability dll. However, what I observe is under the .net6 folder, the libraries of netcoreapp3.0 are present. Not sure why it brings it and also that I am not using "System.Drawing.Common.dll" directly. Is it possible that someother nuget that I use is bringing it?

Comment: Maybe you have older version of `System.Drawing.Common` installed or some package depends on older version of it?

Comment: Something is definitely bringing the package into your project, and the version of the package you're using targets netcoreapp3.0. But that's no different to some other random library having netstandard binaries. It doesn't mean your app is running that runtime, it only means the package contains binaries targeting that TFM as a minimum version. You can find what's brining it into your project by analyzing the `obj/project.assets.json` file.